# how to get key from respective value in a NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to get key from respective value in a NSDictionary?
I am aware of allKeys function but do we have a method which returns a single key for a single value.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well because a value can be in a NSDictionary multiple times, there is no way to just say "Give me the key for this value". But you CAN say "Give me all keys containing this value".

`NSArray* arrayOfKeys = [yourDictionary allKeysForObject:myObject];`

If the value is only once in the dictionary, you can just extract it, using:

`YourObject* o = [arrayOfKeys firstObject];`

But, always do a NIL and count check on this array. Out of bounds exceptions ahead!

P.S. Credits to @Hagile for `firstObject` method instead of `objectAtIndex:0`

Comment: `YourObject *o = [arrayOfKeys firstObject];` would be safe :)

Comment: Not sure if editing code in posts should be done by someone else.